# Step-by-Step SpecFlow testing for Dummies

Tags: testing, specflow

Are there any really simple step-by-step examples/tutorials of how Unit Testing and Specflow testing works and can be done?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are, but the big problem is that to do TDD well and understand how Sepcfication By Example (such as SpecFlow) fits in, I'd recommend that you go a little deeper.

If you start with Gojko Adzic's http://gojko.net/2011/02/04/tdd-breaking-the-mould/ then it hopefully will set the big picture. I would recommend paying close attention to the section with the seven-step tdd or dual cycle section of the talk. For me, the specification by example is the outer circle, when we receive a new business requirement, encode it in Gherkin and use Specflow to validate that the feature doesnt work yet.

Then I recommend the use TDD to help develop your code technically. Use multiple tests to shape the development towards meeting your business goal. Having dome [Keith Braithwaite's TDD as if you mean it](http://gojko.net/2009/02/27/thought-provoking-tdd-exercise-at-the-software-craftsmanship-conference/) exercise I can really recommend you have a go at this.

Finally your TDD drives your Specification to pass, and at this point I would recommend you consider refactoring everything, consider your production code, your unit tests and even your specifications for simplification and duplication removal. Make it clean.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I learned a lot about BDD (and Specification by example) from this presentation by Matt Wynne: http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/agile-scrum/bdd-as-its-meant-to-be-done

It's not SpecFlow but I'm sure you can learn a lot by it anyway.

For the SpecFlow-tooling I would suggest the free TekPub video: http://vimeo.com/46915798.